# CreateProcess running as user: "NT AUTHORITY/Network Service" without knowing the credentials?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-services

I have a windows service running as local system. I would like the service to spawn a process as "NT AUTHORITY/Network Service". However, I do not have the credentials for this account. How can I spawn the process as the "Network Service" user, using c++.

Comment: If you can do this, it would be a really big security hole.

Comment: "If you can do this, it would be a really big security hole" -- how so?  The opposite would be an obvious security hole, if a service running as network service were able to spawn a process as local system.

Comment: @Ken, this feature is actually included by design to *increase* security.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684272%28v=VS.85%29.aspx for the skinny.

Comment: You can LogonUser() with the Network Service account.

Comment: After digging around I posted this question and ended up using `LogonUser()` function. Code sample here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74636046/how-to-start-a-new-process-as-user-nt-authority-network-service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not in front of my win32 dev box, so I can't confirm, but I'll offer two possible approaches:

- Iterate through the list of processes
- Call [`OpenProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the handle of an existing NETWORK SERVICE process
- Call [`OpenProcessToken()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using that handle to get the security token from his process
- Call [`CreateProcessAsUser()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the token to create a process as NETWORK SERVICE

Alternatively, you could:

- Call [`CreateService()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using `NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService` in `lpServiceStartName`
- Call [`StartService()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686321%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to launch the process